# Retrieve friends of weChat ios SDK

Tags: ios, social-networking, wechat

I would like to fetch we chat friends using `weChat SDK iOS`.

I have searched and found nothing which could show me any way to fetch `wechat` friends using `SDK` or any `API`. I am not able to get any link showing that we cannot get we chat friends.

Please anyone who can help me would be appreciable.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you want to get the whole list or just send a message a one of the friends in the WeChat contact list?

Comment: Hi @Suragch is possible to get the list of wechat friends ?

Comment: @AsadullahAli, After [setting up the WeChat API](http://stackoverflow.com/a/35862318) and you share something to it (or even just sharing an image to WeChat without setting up the API), control is given to the WeChat app and the user is given a list of contacts to share the data with. However, I don't know of any way for your actual app to get that list.

Comment: Actually I want to get the list in my app. Can you please let me know if that's possible ?