# Tensorflow iOS returns different results in simple and camera examples using retrained inception model

Tags: ios, machine-learning, tensorflow

I have retrained the inception model to recognize custom set of images. I have tried the simple and camera examples and replaced the .pb and .txt files with my own files. I am able to get a reliable result of probability of 0.99 when using the simple example (replaced the grace_hopper with my image). However, I got different results when using the camera example. I point my camera to the photo but the result seems different from that obtained from simple example. The config I am using is as follows, is there any config I need to make? Thank you.

```
const int wanted_input_width = 299;
const int wanted_input_height = 299;
const int wanted_input_channels = 3;
const float input_mean = 128.0f;
const float input_std = 128.0f;
const std::string input_layer_name = "Mul";
const std::string output_layer_name = "final_result";
```

Comment: I am pinging you here because [your edit got rejected](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/16735105) on my answer about the WeChat API. Actually I think it was probably a good edit, but I am no long maintaining that answer so I don't have time to check it out. If you are willing, could you [add a separate answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35718897/how-to-add-the-wechat-api-to-a-swift-project) explaining how to use CocoaPods and the iOS 9+ changes? I think that would be helpful for others trying to figure out the WeChat API.

Comment: @Suragch Surprised that you're pinging me here. I will post another answer  during my free time as I think my edit is useful because I came across those issues during the setup. Thanks dude.

Comment: Glad to hear it. I pinged you here on a random question because you can't ping the authors of rejected edits directly on the edited question/answer.

Answer (score 1):

The input/output layers have changed between Inception v1 (the version packaged with the Android demo) and v3 (the one you retrained).

You'll need to update the constants found in in [ClassifierActivity.java](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/examples/android/src/org/tensorflow/demo/ClassifierActivity.java) with the values for Inception v3 (also found in the comments there).